# Caramels turn out too sweet

Tags: caramel

I've tried a recipe for caramels that turns out too sweet for my own liking. I substitute agave syrup for corn syrup because it's an invert sugar and I can't find glucose or corn syrup in my area. The recipe itself is 
2 Cups sugar
1.5 cups corn syrup
1 cup butter
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
2 cups heavy cream.
basically is there anything I can do to lower the sweetness?

Comment: Where are you that agave syrup is available, but corn syrup is not?

Comment: Debbie M. - I am currently residing in southern Israel.

Comment: Since it's mostly all sugar, perhaps something to balance out the sweetness somewhat would appeal to your taste— e.g.: coffee or chocolate?

Comment: I've been coating them in dark chocolate and it seems to help a bit but still a bit too sweet.

Comment: So i did some research and flipped through the pages of chocolates and confections and i found that the reason to add invert sugars is to counteract the crystallization by being an interfering, or doctoring, agent. It goes on to list several types of them; glucose syrups, acids, and invert sugars. Since corn syrups and Agave syrups are also considered sweeteners, I'll simply try adding some lemon juice instead. This should invert the sugars in the caramel enough to stop the crystallization process and since it isn't sweet it should lower the sweetness a bit. I'll update when i make it. Thanks!

Comment: Update: made it and still a bit too sweet for my taste. I'll just tough it out I guess. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Bring your sugar to a higher heat, or DARKER. This will create a more bitter-sweet, complex caramel flavour. If you don't bring it dark enough, it'll taste very sweet and bland in comparison.